# Processing huge file in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I have a large file which needs to be uploaded and processed in Laravel. The file is stored in an API server and is processed using a background worker. It is impossible to process the file in one stretch as it will cause PHP memory overflow. So what I am doing is the worker will call API end point which process the file with an offset which will be incremented by 1000 each time. So the API will fetch from this offset and process the data. This process continues until all the records are processed.

Now I would like to know is there any better method for doing this ? I am asking this because the methodology that I am following involves lot of network calls and it will increase as the number of entries in the file grows. Also if a call fails, how can I start from the current offset other than starting again from the beginning ?

Comment: What kind of file? When you say records, is it a database?

Comment: The file is in CSV format and it needs to be processed and inserted to database

Comment: Maybe processing in parallel with multiple threads? You should describe your use case a bit more, though. Are you sure you really need that huge file and there is no way around it?

Comment: nope, It is a huge file anyway and what  I need to do is to take each row from the file validate it and then insert it to the database. Then I need to update the CSV file with status whether the validation is successful or not. This will be added as a new column to the file.